# ¿Qué tipo de campo debo de poner en mi BD si quiero poner un numero telefónico en SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi BD, ya que estoy insertando desde mi formulario PHP en un input a un campo de mi BD de tipo int de 11 longitud, al momento de hacer la inserción me recibe otros números, esto pasa cuando pongo 10 dígitos, cuando pongo 9 me manda el numero correcto, ¿Qué podría estar pasando?

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ultimo es el que tiene 9 digitos.

Comment: No uses un tipo numérico para ese campo, ya que caes en una condición de Overflow. Mejor usar un `varchar` de siempre y limitado a digamos unos 15 caracteres.

Comment: Ah ok muy bien, gracias, es una mala practica?

Comment: No, es sentido común. No vas a realizar operaciones matemáticas con números de teléfono, ya que los mismos no representan cantidades, sólo son etiquetas identificativas.

Comment: Ok gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Dependendo de si vas a almacenar numero telefónicos locales o internacionales yo uso char y asi me aseguro de que cumplan con la cantidad obligatoria según mi uso. en php se puede validar este string con una expresión regular.

Comment: Para números telefónicos se recomienda el [estándar E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164), aunque no pienses usar números internacionales, es recomendable un diseño sólido, porque el contexto puede cambiar en un futuro. Imagina que diseñas pensando sólo en números de un país, y el próximo año hay que incluir números de otros países con distintos formatos, pues te podrías ver un un grave problema para readaptar tu diseño, ya en producción, a ese nuevo requerimiento...

Comment: ... además, no hablamos solamente de teléfonos fijos, sino también de móviles. El estándar E.164 recomienda guardar por un lado el código del pais y por otro el número de abonado. [Revisa este post](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183008-Formatting-International-Phone-Numbers), que puede arrojar luz sobre el asunto, ayudándote a diseñar un modelo resistente a cualquier evolución, y sólido para búsqueda, filtros, organización en base a ese dato, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Buen día...

Primero que nada, debes cambiar los datos de numérico a varchat colocando un número definido de caracteres, ya que esto te va a dar una eficiencia al momento del almacenamiento, por otro lado, debes definir si vas a guardar o no el código del país, porque no lo veo en el campo y esto sería muy útil a la hora de ordenamientos y consultas.

Aquí tienes un código suponiendo que el número máximo son 10 dígitos con paréntesis y guiones, validado con una expresión regular en PHP:

```
<?php
function validarTelefono($numero){
  $reg = "#^\(\d{3}\)[\s\.-]\d{3}[\s\.-]\d{4}$#";
  return preg_match($reg, $numero);
}
//ejemplo:
if(validarTelefono("(214)-748-3647")){
  echo "teléfono válido";
} else {
  echo "teléfono inválido";
}
?>
```

Es importante que esta expresión regular también la coloques en el campo de inserción haciendo la doble validación, recuerda ayudar al usuario colocando un placeholder.

Como no especificas que estás usando de frontend aquí un ejemplo en HTML:

```
<input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="(XXX)-XXX-XXXX" pattern="^\(\d{3}\)[\s\.-]\d{3}[\s\.-]\d{4}$">
```

Comment: La respuesta no esta mal, pero por ejemplo yo no podria agregar mi numero de telefono ahi... hay que tener cuidado... y aclarar que esto es solamente un ejemplo...

Comment: @gbianchi la respuesta tiene el código para teléfonos de 3 dígitos de localidad y 7 de identificación y obliga a los 10 dígitos que él está exigiendo como resultado, si necesita un formato específico no lo dijo, es obvio que lo demás es un plus que debe tomar en cuanta y es claro que no es para tu número de teléfono porque no soy adivino jejejeje.. Saludos Maestro.

Comment: Alberto a lo que se refiere  @gbianchi es que eso solo funcionaria para un pais pero si yo quiero meter mi numero que es +34 6xx xxx xxx pues ya me daría un pete, debe buscar algún modo como por ejemplo un if que si empieza por 34 pues entonces esta expresión regular , puedes hacer prueba en esta pagina que tengo https://javiergraya.000webhostapp.com/expresionesRegulares.html